# how can make next button to the 10 divs in html

Tags: html

My project is about 10 divs

in each div I put an image

how can move by divs by next button

```html
<body>
<div 
   id="1" 
  <img id="img" src="image1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div 
   id="2" 
  <img id="img" src="image2.jpg"/>
</div>
<div 
   id="3" 
  <img id="img" src="image3.jpg"/>
</div>
<div 
   id="4" 
  <img id="img" src="image1.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean make a div appear one after another by pressing a next button, you would first of all have to include a next button: `<button onclick="next()">Next</button>`

Then you would have to make each div except for the first one not appear. You can do this is CSS by adding a class to all those DIVs : `<div class="hidden">` and in CSS add style for the class hidden : `.hidden { display:none; }`.

Then apply the class `.hidden` to each of the DIVs except the first one.

Then finally you have to add the JavaScript for the function `next()` so in a new `script`. I have added it to the JS Bin: http://output.jsbin.com/qulobidahu

And the ID's for your images shouldn't all be the same since IDs are meant to be unique. Hope this helps!

Comment: I can not understand you>> can you explain more

Comment: where can I put the button>> and how can I hide the div?

Answer (score 0):

Please end the element with `>` in your div like: `<div id="1">`
Here's the correct Code:

```
<body>
<div id="1"> 
  <img id="img" src="image1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="2"> 
  <img id="img" src="image2.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <img id="img" src="image3.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="4"> 
  <img id="img" src="image1.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
```